# How to install Bob using Conda on Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, python-bob

I have tried installing conda and then [Bob](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob) in Google colab but it still fails to import Bob. Here is a notebook that demonstrates the issue: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ns_pjEN0fFY5dNAO0FNLAG422APFu-NI

The steps are:

```
%%bash
# based on https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522
MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT=Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
MINICONDA_PREFIX=/usr/local
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
chmod +x $MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
./$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT -b -f -p $MINICONDA_PREFIX
```

```
!conda install --channel defaults conda python=3.6 --yes --quiet
```

```
!conda install --yes --quiet --override-channels \
  -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda -c defaults \
  python=3.6 bob.io.image bob.bio.face # add more Bob packages here as needed
```

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages")
```

```
import pkg_resources
import bob.extension, bob.io.base, bob.io.image
```

which produces:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-8e8041c9e60e> in <module>()
      1 import pkg_resources
----> 2 import bob.extension, bob.io.base, bob.io.image

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bob'
```

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe. As written presently, there's not enough information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I did the installation of  bob in my environment which I already created  ( !source activate bob_env1
!conda install bob.core )     the installation is done successfully but when I import  bob.core or an other sub-package ( !source activate bob_env1
import bob.core) an error indicates that  " No module named 'bob'"

Comment: Dear Rania, please share a notebook with us that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @183.amir Thankyou for your reply, the error has changed but it remains in the same context  ` !source activate bob_env1
!conda install bob `  the installation is done successfully  but when i do ` !source activate bob_env1
import bob
import bob.core `    this error is displayed    ` ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DistributionNotFound                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-c88d7acf32fb> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('source activate bob_env1')
      2 import bob
----> 3 import bob.core

Comment: @183.amir  4 import bob.io.base
      5 import bob.learn.em

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve (self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    784 if dist is None:
    785 requirers = required_by.get (req, None)
-> 786 raise DistributionNotFound (req, requirers)
    787 to_activate.append (dist)
    788 if dist not in req:

DistributionNotFound: The 'bob.extension' distribution was not found and is required by the application `I hope you understand me

Comment: Here is a link to google colab where I tried to install Conda first and then Bob but for some reason I cannot make it work: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ns_pjEN0fFY5dNAO0FNLAG422APFu-NI?usp=sharing Maybe @BobSmith can help?

Comment: still in the same problem